# Scala - Duplicates removal from List

Tags: scala, list, duplicates

I need the duplicates to be removed from a List. I have created the code below, but it throws an error.  What am I missing here?

```
object RemDupArray {
  def duprmv(lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = { return lst.removeDuplicates }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var xs = List(6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1)    
    println(xs)
    println(duprmv(xs))
  }
}
```

Comment: `removeDuplicates`  is deprecated, what error you are getting? Can you post full code and the error you are getting.

Comment: show us the error please

Comment: Use a `Set[Int]` instead. Sets have no repetition and no order.

Comment: What's up with `duprmv`? Did the store where you normally buy your letters run out of vowels today?

Answer (score 4):

`removeDuplicates` is not a member of List in Scala, use `distinct` instead.

Change your code to:

```
object RemDupArray {

    def duprmv(lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = lst.distinct

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var xs = List(6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1)    
        println(xs)
        println(duprmv(xs))
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also emphasize the fact that `return` should be avoided in Scala :)

Answer (score 3):

The method you are looking for is `distinct`.

Replace `return lst.removeDuplicates`  with  `lst.distinct`.

Comment: Thanks! Edited the answer.

Comment: Does `List.distinct` preserve ordering? It might not be appropriate if not and the remaining elements must be kept in their initial relative order.

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy solutions:

1. use List.distinct method
2. transform your list in a set, that by definition has no duplicated elements (keep in mind you will lose order, if that's relevant)

code:

```
def duprmv_1(lst: List[Int]): Set[Int] = lst.distinct

def duprmv_2(lst: List[Int]): Set[Int] = lst.toSet
```

Comment: Thanks folks... Appreciate your help !

Comment: consider upvoting working solutions/answers, and choose one as correct if your problem was solved @RameshLakshman :)